# Does a wildcard subdomain (*.example.com) in Apache config also include the root (example.com)?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, httpd.conf, wildcard

Does anything in an Apache config file (like `ServerAlias`, `RewriteRule`, ...) that has a wildcarded line like

```
*.example.com
```

also include the root

```
example.com
```

or do I have to separately add this entry (like `ServerAlias *.example.com example.com`)?

Comment: Right away I don't see why a wildcard after a dot would match something that doesn't even have a dot in it. Why not try it? Then you can just answer the question and maybe get some rep out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `*.example.com` does not match `example.com`.  You're missing at least a dot, see? Right before "example".

Edit: Apache [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html) backing this up. In fact, they specifically advise using `ServerAlias`:

```
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
```